# Why does median imputation does not work?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinyapps

I'm developing a ShinyApp where is some place i use some conditions like this:

```
     if(AggActive){
      tbl = tbl %>% 
        spread(key = "Agg_BoxType",value = "Supply_Counts",fill = 0) %>% 
        left_join(dgs10, by = c("Day"="Date")) %>% 
        mutate(DGS10 = ifelse(is.na(DGS10),median(DGS10,na.rm = T),DGS10))
    }else{
      tbl = tbl %>%
        mutate(Key = paste(Channel,Box_Type,sep = "_")) %>%
        select(Day, Key,Supply_Counts) %>%
        spread(key = "Key",value = "Supply_Counts",fill = 0) %>%
        left_join(dgs10, by = c("Day"="Date")) %>%
        mutate(DGS10 = ifelse(is.na(DGS10),median(DGS10,na.rm = T),DGS10))
    }
```

The problem is that for the first part of the 'If' condition the last mutate which replace NA values by the median does not work. The NAs are always there. If I replace the median by a numeric value it works. However for the second part of the 'If' It always works.
Do you remark anything that is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide example data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say without the data; one problem could be that if there are only `NA`s in `DGS10`

Comment: Good point by @starja. Check if there is any non-NA values are left? e.g.: `median(c(NA,NA))` and `median(c(NA,NA), na.rm = TRUE))` both would give you NA.

Comment: Actually there is a lot non NA values in DGS10. And as I said the median imputation work fine for the else block.

Comment: What error are you getting for the part that's not working?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The values just still NA.

Comment: I just tried the easy way and it wroks: tbl$DGS10[is.na(tbl$DGS10)] <- mean(tbl$DGS10,na.rm = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. There is no time to waste. so I just instead of using the mutate i used a straightforward imputation.

```
     if(AggActive){
  tbl = tbl %>% 
    spread(key = "Agg_BoxType",value = "Supply_Counts",fill = 0) %>% 
    left_join(dgs10, by = c("Day"="Date"))
   tbl$DGS10[is.na(tbl$DGS10)] <- mean(tbl$DGS10,na.rm = TRUE) 
}else{
  tbl = tbl %>%
    mutate(Key = paste(Channel,Box_Type,sep = "_")) %>%
    select(Day, Key,Supply_Counts) %>%
    spread(key = "Key",value = "Supply_Counts",fill = 0) %>%
    left_join(dgs10, by = c("Day"="Date"))
  tbl$DGS10[is.na(tbl$DGS10)] <- mean(tbl$DGS10,na.rm = TRUE)
}
```